# how to echo needs with matrix in github action?

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to run below command

```
      echo ${{ steps.microservices-cache.outputs.cache-hit }} 
      echo ${{needs.directory.outputs."${{ matrix.check-file-changed }}" }}
      if [ "${{ steps.microservices-cache.outputs.cache-hit }}" != 'true' ] || [ "${{ needs.directory.outputs.${{ matrix.check-file-changed }} }}" == 'true' ]; then
        echo "true"
      else
        echo "false"
      fi
```

but I guess this expression is not correct

```
${{needs.directory.outputs."${{ matrix.check-file-changed }}" }}
```

getting this error:

```
Unexpected symbol: '${{'. Located at position 35 within expression: needs.directory-inspector.outputs.${{ matrix.check-file-changed
```

could someone please let me know the error in above code

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I wonder why you wouldn't be able to resolve it at the matrix strategy level. Could you share the whole workflow implementation to have more context please (with both job, the first one creating the needs outputs, and the second one with the matrix configuration) ?